# Puzzle about total winnings in a card game

Tags: puzzle

Mr. White is playing with Mr. Green. They decided that stake of every round will be 50% of total money that Mr. Green has. Mr. Green said that he has in total 32$.

So in the first round stake was 16$. They played for 7 rounds and Mr. Green won 4 of them.

**How much money Mr. Green has?**

In my opinion Mr Green has just 40$ now and the order of winnigs have nothing to do with it because we have to do with geomtrical sequence here. He won 4 times loose 3 times.

Comment: if he lost the first three, wouldn't it be $32 \mapsto 16 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 4$ and then won 4: $4 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 9 \mapsto 13.5 \mapsto 20.25$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the order of wins and losses don't matter, though your answer is incorrect.

When Mr. Green wins he gets half of his current total back, or $1.5$ of his total as an end result. When he loses it's half the money, or $0.5$ of the total.

$$32\cdot1.5^4\cdot0.5^3=20.25$$